# Storing leftover hops using water displacement method

Tags: hops, storage

Has anyone tried using [water displacement method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrZPLF0ezw8) for sealing leftover hops? I realise you'd normally want to keep hops pretty far away from water. But you also want to keep it far away from O<sub>2</sub> as well. Squeezing zip lock bags seems common enough.

I just had a delivery of last years hop harvest and it didn't come in bags that are suitable for resealing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Actually using plastic bags period is bad**, because they are permeable (small molecules can pass through)

So even submerging the bag to vacate air really won't do much good.

You're better off investing in a Mylar bagger, or using mason jars purged with nitro or c02.

Update: I simply just use a straw to suck out as much air as possible and reseal the Mylar bag with the zip lock style internal bag. Then **use foil tape** over the cut edge of the mylar. The hops I buy are in this style of bag, it may not be the case with most. I tend to buy 8oz min sizes.

Comment: You can use Mylar bags with a foodsaver sealer with some minor hacks.

Comment: Using water displacement method would not work with mylar bags. They are too rigid.

Comment: I'm considering buying some oxygen absorbers and resealing Mylar.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah sure, I don't see why not. The hops are probably not sinking as easy as the steak, but it will still work if you be careful enough.

But also I'm thinking that you won't notice a difference between a bag that contains 2% O2 and another one (without the water displacement method) that contains 20%.

Are you going to freeze the hops afterwards?

Comment: Sure l’m freezing them as well. More careful now. I bought some hops from a local brew shop. But those hops were stale/flat.